# Visual Studio Online permissions remove access to Code

Tags: user-permissions, azure-devops

Is it possible to remove permissions to the Code in Visual Studio Online, for a given user or user group?

For example, I'd like to disable access to the source code for the testers.

Comment: Define remove: cannot read and write, or cannot write only?